# Use rsync to copy current directory without specifying current directory's name

Tags: rsync

Is there a way to copy the current directory (and not just the contents) to a remote directory -- without specifying the current directory by name.

For example, I'm in the directory /bar and I want to copy /bar and its contents to the remote directory /foo with the resulting directory being /foo/bar.

Of course I could specify the current directory by name, but I'd just to be able to copy, in the manner specified, whatever directory I'm in.

Comment: "Basically, I'm looking for something like . ( e.g., 'rsync -r . remote@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) but that will include the current directory itself." -- so if you're not hoping to include the current directory, isn't your question (to copy the current directory) not what you want?

Comment: Why not just use the name of it via pwd? Then you dont need to know its name because you have it.

Comment: matrixanomaly -- sorry, that example was confusing. Deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want in my tests unless I am miss understanding you:

```
rsync -r `pwd` user@hosts:./bar
```

Assuming you have:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 in ~/foo
○ → ls -l 
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 errr  staff  0 May  9 13:07 bah
-rw-r--r--  1 errr  staff  0 May  9 13:07 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 errr  staff  0 May  9 13:07 baz

Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 in ~/foo
○ → rsync -r `pwd` errr@192.168.88.217:./bar
errr@192.168.88.217's password:
```

You end up with:

```
errr@ansible-master:~/bar$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 errr errr 4096 May  9 18:10 foo

./foo:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 errr errr 0 May  9 18:10 bah
-rw-r--r-- 1 errr errr 0 May  9 18:10 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 errr errr 0 May  9 18:10 baz
```

Comment: Yes!  This is the idea! However it seems to fail for directories with spaces in the names. Works from within directory /foo, but not from within  /foo\ foo.

Comment: Got it....just use "`pwd`".  Thanks for your help. I'd Vote Up (since you did precisely answer my question as worded" but I don't have the rep.